# Как изменить сообщение disnake

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно отредактировать сообщение через `disnake`. Уверен что это крайне легко но у меня не получается.

```
message = await inter.response.send_message(embed = k, delete_after = 5)
await asyncio.sleep(1)
await disnake.message.edit(embed = n)
await asyncio.sleep(1)
await disnake.message.edit(embed = res)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
await inter.edit_original_response(embed = n) #изменяет сообщение.
await asyncio.sleep(1) #ждём
await inter.edit_original_response(embed = res) #изменяем ещё раз.
```